# The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version: project ':sign_in_with_apple' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50

Tags: flutter, firebase, dependencies, sign-in-with-apple

i have been issueing this problem when i installed a new system on my hard drive. I import the project and then built the gradle. as the problem appears i tried too check . i found out that the problem appears when i install fireflutter dependency. But this dependency is needed in the project . Please help me... its have been 1 months and i still can't find the solution

here is my gradle file

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}
def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '26'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.1.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'applovin-quality-service'
applovin {
    apiKey "**********"
}
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

  defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "*********"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 26
        versionName "1.1.2"
        multiDexEnabled true
        
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2G"
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.applovin:applovin-sdk:+'
    // implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.4.0'
    // implementation 'com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:7.1.11'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I try flutter clean and flutter pub get but nothing seems to be working... i removed the fireflutter dependency and have installed some other dependencies and the app built... but now i cant send local notification or firebase notification